# Delete operation is forbidden for current area error when creating account from checkout success page

Tags: magento2, checkout, order-success-page

When creating an account from the checkout success page the following error is shown.

**"Delete operation is forbidden for current area"**

Console shows:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable) /checkout/account/create/
```

Error in the logs for this page reads:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:71:"A customer with the same email already exists in an associated website.";i:1;s:10181:"#0
```

This is a completely new email address, however. I have tried replicating this issue on a separate server to try and debug this.

This does not seem to be a problem with any code or modifications made by me I'm starting to think it is just a bug as after multiple attempts to replicate on almost Vanilla Magento 2 I think Its simply that if Address line 2 is left blank. Can anyone else replicate this on Magento 2.1.6?

Answer (score 0):

This 503 error occurs when you click on 'create new account' button more then one time.
The process, which is creating new account is in progress after you click at first time. So if you click button at the second time, it shows you 503 error 'Service Temporarily Unavailable', because process is busy.